# Access values of Behavior Subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I realise there are several questions on this on StackOverflow and I'm still working my way through them.

I am trying to access the values of a behavior subject but obviously don't understand enough to get there. I've read through the rxjs docs and various other sources. I have tried creating a new BehaviourSubject, using next, subscribing to it, etc. Also tried using pipe & map to map it out.

```
this.theService.items$
```

is an Observable - Behavior Subject, which has a private field _values, which I am trying to access but can't. And then project that to a variable so I can access the field values and use in my component.

items$ is a getter to retrieve the observable

```
private _items$ = new BehaviorSubject<T[]>([]);
get items$() {
    return this._items$.asObservable();
  }
```

I want something like this, which I found tbh without finding an item based on its id

```
public model: IModel; 

this.theService.items$.pipe(
  map(items => <IModel>items.find(item => item.ID === this.id))).subscribe(item => {
    this.model = item
});
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to get the values from `BehaviorSubject` directly - you need to call `BehaviorSubject.value`.

so you can expose to method in your service:

```
private _items$ = new BehaviorSubject<T[]>([]);
get items$() {
  return this._items$.asObservable();
}
get items() {
   return this._items$.value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So simple. I had looked at .value but didn't realise I could just use it like this.